# Why cannot gdb access memory of ret instruction?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

every `call` in asm, causes that instruction `push`es return value, so once `ret` is called, the program knows where to continue. So I would like to examine the address upon which `ret` is called:

having this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("a=%d; b=%d; c=%d", 1, 2, 3);
return 0;
}
```

I use gdb:

```
(gdb) b printf
+b printf
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1030
(gdb) run
+run
Breakpoint 1, __printf (format=0x555555556004 "a=%d; b=%d; c=%d")
    at printf.c:28
28  printf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) x/10x $rsp
+x/10x $rsp
0x7fffffffdc28: 0x55555159  0x00005555  0x55555160  0x00005555
0x7fffffffdc38: 0xf7e1c09b  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffdc48: 0xffffdd18  0x00007fff

(gdb) x/i 0x55555159
+x/i 0x55555159
   0x55555159:  Cannot access memory at address 0x55555159
(gdb)
```

Here I am trying to read instruction from return address, but somehow cannot access that address. Why, when it should be valid address for `ret`?

Comment: It looks like addresses are 64 bits in your program, and they occupy two of the 32-bit words shown by `gdb`. Try `x/i 0x555555555159`.

Comment: but why they occupy x32word on x64 machine?

Comment: The debugger is showing you 32-bit words because that is what the `x` in `/10x` means. It has modifiers to say to show the data in groups of other sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eric Postpischil commented, you are only examining *half* of the return address, which 64-bit on `x86_64`.

Using your program:

```
(gdb) b printf
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1030
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, __printf (format=0x555555556004 "a=%d; b=%d; c=%d") at printf.c:28
28      printf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __printf (format=0x555555556004 "a=%d; b=%d; c=%d") at printf.c:28
#1  0x0000555555555159 in main () at t.c:4
```

This shows that the return address we expect to find on the stack is `0x0000555555555159`. Indeed, that is exactly the address @`$rsp`:

```
(gdb) x/gx $rsp
0x7fffffffdbd8: 0x0000555555555159
```

To see the instruction at that address:

```
(gdb) x/i 0x0000555555555159
   0x555555555159 <main+36>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
```

You can also disassemble the whole `main` to see where you are and where you are going to return:

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000555555555135 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000555555555136 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000555555555139 <+4>:     mov    $0x3,%ecx
   0x000055555555513e <+9>:     mov    $0x2,%edx
   0x0000555555555143 <+14>:    mov    $0x1,%esi
   0x0000555555555148 <+19>:    lea    0xeb5(%rip),%rdi        # 0x555555556004
   0x000055555555514f <+26>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000555555555154 <+31>:    callq  0x555555555030 <printf@plt>
   0x0000555555555159 <+36>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000055555555515e <+41>:    pop    %rbp
   0x000055555555515f <+42>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

As you can see, the instruction that `printf` will return to is indeed at address `0x0000555555555159`.